# jQuery - Click Event Only Firing Once

Tags: html, jquery, css, events, dom-events

I have a click function which is only firing the first time that it's activated.

Basically I have a Bootstrap 4 site and when I open any of the dropdown menus I want to add a class to the header. When I click on the "ul li" it logs "test" in the console as per my code, but when I click it again to close the menu and again, and again etc. it doesn't ever output the console log message ever again.

```
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-nav li', function() {
    console.log('test');
    $('.navbar-nav li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
            // Add Class Code
        }
    });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="navbar-nav"><li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-62 nav-item"><a title="Golf" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-62">Golf</a>
    <div class="dropdown_wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row w-100">
                <div class="col-12 position-unset">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-62" role="menu">
                        <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-78 nav-item">
                            <a title="Golf Courses" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Golf Courses</a> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-72" class="box_button menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-72 nav-item">
    <a title="Course Update" href="#" class="nav-link">Course Update</a>
</li>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. You can click on `<>` in question editor and include the bootstrap resources to make it run right here in the page

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
$('.navbar-nav').find('li').on('click', e => {
  console.log('test');
    
  if ($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('show')) {
    // Add Class Code
  }
})
```

Try this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all and doesn't actually log the test.

Comment: Could you provide a codepen that we can reproduce it? @LewisHardisty I´ve just edited the code. Try it now, please!

Comment: This is logging 'test' however it's only firing once unfortunately.

Comment: It will be better if you provide a codepen with your code and what you want to achieve.

Comment: if it´s firing once is because you´re having another error on your javascript. Try to isolate everything and you will see that the console.log is printed everytime you click on the selected element

Comment: Please see the attached JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wzr9361q/ You'll see that it only alerts once, not a second or a third time etc. when you click on the dropdown.

Comment: Alerting once, on every click, is exactly what is expected with the code provided in the JSFiddle. Please give a better explanation of what you want.